# How to use currencyStyle number as double value iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, localization, currency

I have a rupees with currency symbol in a text box for ex : Rs 10,500.50
and i want to use it in a calculation as 10500*5. 
How can i use this. when i try to convert it into double value then it returns 0.00. please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've used an NSNumberFormatter to format the text string, you can use the same formatter to parse the text string back into a number.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSNumber *rupees = [NSNUmber numberWithFloat:10500.50];

NSString *formattedRupees = [formatter stringFromNumber:rupees];

NSNumber *rupeesFromString = [formatter numberFromString:formattedRupees];

[formatter release];
```

If you're not using an NSNumberFormatter, you could try using an NSScanner to parse the string manually.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. but i want to convert 10,500.00 to 10500.00. so i can use in a calculation. plz suggest me asap. thx

Comment: NSNumber *rupeesFromString = [formatter numberFromString:formattedRupees]; from above.

Answer (score 0):

**Careful with Float numbers!!**

Using `NSNumber *rupees = [NSNUmber numberWithFloat:10500.50];` may cause precision issues in the conversion. The '10500.50f' number may work, but if you try something like 25.63f, this might happen:

```
rupees = 25.629999
```

That's why using floats and doubles in currencies is not recommended.

**Moving to your question:**

you can do something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"Rs 10,500.50";
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Rs " withString:@""];

NSArray *valueArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSInteger firstNumber = [[valueArray firstObject] intValue];
NSInteger secondNumber = [[valueArray lastObject] intValue];
```

And then you can use both values (`firstNumber` and `secondNumber`)